# ordering alphabetically in a select_tag, joined table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, html-select

I have this line of code:

```
 <%= select_tag :friendship_id, options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.friendships, "id", "name", selected = nil) %>
```

Which selects the 'name' of the record in the 'friends' table and puts it as an option on the select_tag

Friendships has a friendship_id that links to the friends table. I call the name using

```
def name
  self.friend.name
end
```

In the friendships controller

The association works cause I see the list of names on the webpage.

I would like to:

1. order that alphabetically
2. add a "select a friend..." at the top of the list

And I haven't really found anything yet.
For issue 2, i add selected = nil to no avail.

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT (ANSWER):

I ended up chaging the way the collection was fetched, and looked for the friends instead of the friendships.

```
 <%= select_tag :friend_id, options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.friends, "id", "name"), :prompt => 'Select a friend...', :id => 'thought_contact_select' %>
```

In my User model

```
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :order => :name
```

The i just look for the friendship associated for that friend and that user on the controller

```
friendship = Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(current_user.id, params[:friend_id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use default_scope :name but use it once! You should have one default scope. Or, as you are accessing the friendships through `has_many` association use `has_many :friendships, :order => 'name DESC'` see description of `has_many` here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
2. Use `:prompt` option to `select_tag`, see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

**EDIT:**

If I understood you, you should have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :friend
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :friendships
   has_many :users, :through => :friendships
end
```

Try to change the `User` class to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :friendships
   has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :order => 'name'
end
```

Comment: Number 2 issue solved!. However, Number 1 issue doesn't work, cause i'm calling current_user.friendships, and name is in a third table called friends, so it gives me the error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships"  WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = 6 ORDER BY name DESC`